# http: panic serving [::1]:54831: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: mongodb, go

I am currently working on a feature where I will be able to see all the tweets from the users I follow, i am testing it using Postman, but I cannot figure out what the issue is, I know it has to do with a nil or pointer deference, but I haven't been able to figure it out despite the careful readings I have done on my code. I am pretty much new to Go and this is the first language I learn that uses this sort of syntax and that uses pointers so I apologize in advanced if it is something obvious I am not seeing.
**On my db package**

```
package db

import (
    "context"
    "time"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/JeffersonGarcia15/Twitter-Clone/models"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
)

/*
ReadFollowersTweets reads the tweets from my followers
*/

func ReadFollowersTweets(ID string, page int) ([]models.ReturnFollowersTweets, bool) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 15*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    db := MongoCN.Database("twitter")
    col := db.Collection("joins")

    skip := (page - 1) * 20

    conditions := make([]bson.M, 0)
    conditions = append(conditions, bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"userid": ID}})
    conditions = append(conditions, bson.M{
        "$lookup": bson.M{
            "from":         "tweets",
            "localField":   "userrelationid",
            "foreignField": "userid",
            "as":           "tweets",
        }})
    conditions = append(conditions, bson.M{"unwind": "$tweets"}) //allows all the info to be repeated with the same structure for all tweets on same page
    conditions = append(conditions, bson.M{"$sort": bson.M{"date": "desc"}})
    conditions = append(conditions, bson.M{"$skip": skip})
    conditions = append(conditions, bson.M{"$limit": 20})

    cursor, err := col.Aggregate(ctx, conditions)
    var result []models.ReturnFollowersTweets

    err := cursor.All(ctx, &result)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return result, false
    }
    return result, true

}
```

***On routers***

package routers

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
    "github.com/JeffersonGarcia15/Twitter-Clone/db"
)

/*
ReadFollowersTweets reads the tweets of all our followers
*/

func ReadFollowersTweets(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if len(r.URL.Query().Get("page")) < 1 {
        http.Error(w, "You must send a page number", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    page, err := strconv.Atoi(r.URL.Query().Get("page"))
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "You must send a page number as an int greater than 0"+err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    response, correct := db.ReadFollowersTweets(IDUser, page)
    if !correct {
        http.Error(w, "An error occurred when reading the tweets", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(response)
}
```

**Error in console**

```
2021/10/04 10:24:46 http: panic serving [::1]:55085: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 164 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1()
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1801 +0xb9
panic({0x14bbac0, 0x1985c40})
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:1047 +0x266
go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo.(*Cursor).closeImplicitSession(0x10526ff)
        /Users/jeffersonlopezgarcia/go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.7.2/mongo/cursor.go:267 +0x14
panic({0x14bbac0, 0x1985c40})
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:1038 +0x215
go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo.(*Cursor).Close(0x0, {0x16755a8, 0xc000416360})
        /Users/jeffersonlopezgarcia/go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.7.2/mongo/cursor.go:180 +0x5f
panic({0x14bbac0, 0x1985c40})
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:1038 +0x215
go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo.(*Cursor).All(0x0, {0x16755a8, 0xc000416360}, {0x1487380, 0xc00000e600})
        /Users/jeffersonlopezgarcia/go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.7.2/mongo/cursor.go:209 +0x1fe
github.com/JeffersonGarcia15/Twitter-Clone/db.ReadFollowersTweets({0xc0000fc0c0, 0x18}, 0x1)
        /Users/jeffersonlopezgarcia/go/src/github.com/JeffersonGarcia15/Twitter-Clone/db/readFollowersTweets.go:41 +0x8c9
github.com/JeffersonGarcia15/Twitter-Clone/routers.ReadFollowersTweets({0x1673cd0, 0xc000588700}, 0xc000684300)
        /Users/jeffersonlopezgarcia/go/src/github.com/JeffersonGarcia15/Twitter-Clone/routers/readFollowersTweets.go:24 +0x10a
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(...)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2046
github.com/JeffersonGarcia15/Twitter-Clone/middlew.ValidJWT.func1({0x1673cd0, 0xc000588700}, 0xc000684300)
        /Users/jeffersonlopezgarcia/go/src/github.com/JeffersonGarcia15/Twitter-Clone/middlew/validJWT.go:20 +0xb2
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(...)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2046
github.com/JeffersonGarcia15/Twitter-Clone/middlew.CheckDB.func1({0x1673cd0, 0xc000588700}, 0xc00059a600)
        /Users/jeffersonlopezgarcia/go/src/github.com/JeffersonGarcia15/Twitter-Clone/middlew/checkDB.go:18 +0xa9
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc000684200, {0x1673cd0, 0xc000588700}, 0xc0000a2701)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2046 +0x2f
github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP(0xc0004ba240, {0x1673cd0, 0xc000588700}, 0xc000684100)
        /Users/jeffersonlopezgarcia/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gorilla/mux@v1.8.0/mux.go:210 +0x1cf
github.com/rs/cors.(*Cors).Handler.func1({0x1673cd0, 0xc000588700}, 0xc000684100)
        /Users/jeffersonlopezgarcia/go/pkg/mod/github.com/rs/cors@v1.8.0/cors.go:219 +0x1bd
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc000559819, {0x1673cd0, 0xc000588700}, 0x106236e)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2046 +0x2f
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP({0xc00059a450}, {0x1673cd0, 0xc000588700}, 0xc000684100)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2878 +0x43b
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc00031d4a0, {0x16755e0, 0xc00059a2d0})
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1929 +0xb08
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:3033 +0x4e8
```

Comment: Do not ignore the error from  `coll.Aggregate`

Comment: I just edited to bring back that error but the issue still exists. Thanks though for pointing that out.

Comment: Does this mean there is no error?

Comment: Hi Burak, it seems that the error is still there. I try a new test with postman and it pretty much prints the same.  It still talks about invalid memory address or nil pointer deference

Comment: @AdilsonJurado: you are assigning the `err` value, but you are still not handling the error at all.

Comment: That's not what I meant. What I meant is that is there a non-nil error from `coll.Aggregate`. Based on your updated code, you are still ignoring the error.

Comment: JimB @Burak thanks so much guys the issue was on the unwind, it needed a $ and also instead of "desc" you use -1. Thanks guys! I learned not to ignore errors now :D!

Comment: Other good lessons here: always include complete relevant code -ideally something we can actually compile - as well as the full error output.  We never would have figured this out without that stuff.  And a final one: be very careful to post the correct code, not just something that looks similar - these details matter!  Case in point, some of your code doesn't actually ompile because `no new variables on left side of :=`

Comment: missing return statement [here](https://github.com/JeffersonGarcia15/Twitter-Clone/blob/47dc091ee98db71ad3fc9d54430febeec77d34d4/db/readFollowersTweets.go#L41)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line from the stack trace that's in your code is:

```
/Users/jeffersonlopezgarcia/go/src/github.com/JeffersonGarcia15/Twitter-Clone/db/readFollowersTweets.go:41
```

That appears to be, from the quoted code:

```
err := cursor.All(ctx, &result)
```

Let's see, how could that cause `nil` pointer? Let's see where the relevant parts are initialized.

```
cursor, _ := col.Aggregate(ctx, conditions)
```

You're discarding an error here, so it seems pretty likely this is your cause. *Never* discard your errors, *especially* when something is failing and you can't figure out why. That should always be the first thing you look for.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I just added the err back and updated my question to reflect changes in that line of code, and what the console prints once I try testing with postman. It seems to be pointing to the same line still I believe.

Comment: In case someone is having a similar issue but *not* seeing the right file/line number for the error, for me it ended up being http.TimeoutHandler eating stack frames: github.com/golang/go/issues/27375